# Entity Framework 3.1 Execute Migrations From Assembly

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

We've just upgraded a .NET Core 2.1 application to .NET Core 3.1.
We used to execute migrations using `dotnet exec`, pointing to the project's dll files, and it all worked perfectly, until the upgrade. Executing migrations based on the assembly is vital, because the service user has weak permissions, and can't manipulate the database scheme, and can only perform read/write operations.

Now we are getting an error:

> Your startup project doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, although it is referenced.

Comment: See the following EF 3.0 breaking change - [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is now a DevelopmentDependency package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#microsoftentityframeworkcoredesign-is-now-a-developmentdependency-package)

Comment: Tried it, still no go.
Resolved by creating a console appication that just calls db.Database.Migrate() on the DbContext.